# Need client messaging in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, text-messaging

I have 19 PC's running Ubuntu. I want 18 of these PCs to be able to send some message to the first PC. So, the first PC can receive all message from another PCs.

But, the 1 PC is not a server. It just a client but another client just send

I don't know which software I should use.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [talk](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/talk/), a command-line based program for this purpose.

I believe it's installed by default, if not try `sudo apt-get install inetutils-talk`.

Package info found [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/inetutils-talk).

Comment: but this should be use terminal,isn't it? i want like some desktop app. And i worry to use because of this article `http://wpedia.goo.ne.jp/enwiki/User_talk:217.85.214.167`.

Answer (score 1):

Pidgin and Empathy support Bonjour network-local messaging. (avahi-daemon is needed.)